# GFI outlets not working - resets working

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

4 outside GFI outlets and 2 in the garage not working. One in the garage has a GFI red light. The light is powered on, but outlet doesn't work. The Elec Panel GFI is not tripped. Help

Comment: How many GFIs are on this circuit?

Comment: GFI's come in two types. One will have a light on when it is working and one that comes on when it is in tripped position and it is usually red. So you probably need to reset that GFI.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few GFCIs have a light that comes on when the GFCI has been tripped. You should press the Reset button.

If the outlet refuses to reset it has gone bad and will need replacing.